# ZFS not installed into upgraded kernel (4.19)

Tags: zfs, apt, zfsonlinux, kernel-modules

I want to use the latest kernel (currently 4.19) with Ubuntu Server 18.04, and I also want to use ZFS.

Although ZFS appears to install correctly, it apparently does not get installed into the right kernel. Is there something additional I need to do to get kernel module like ZFS to install into the right kernel? Or do I need to build it specially for my kernel until a backport is provided?

Also, I did install the new kernel before installing ZFS. Previously I had tried upgrading the kernel after installing ZFS, which broke ZFS and gave me a "no installation candidate" message when I tried to reinstall it from that version.

```
~$ zpool list
The ZFS modules are not loaded.
Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.
~$ sudo /sbin/modprobe zfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.6-041906-generic
~$ sudo apt install -y zfsutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zfsutils-linux' instead of 'zfsutils'
zfsutils-linux is already the newest version (0.7.5-1ubuntu16.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 127 not upgraded.
~$ sudo apt install zfs-initramfs 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zfs-initramfs is already the newest version (0.7.5-1ubuntu16.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 127 not upgraded.

~$ ls /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel
arch   crypto   fs      lib  net    ubuntu  zfs
block  drivers  kernel  mm   sound  virt
~$ ls /lib/modules/4.19.6-041906-generic/kernel
arch  block  crypto  drivers  fs  kernel  lib  mm  net  sound  virt
```

Comment: How did you install ZFS?

Comment: It installed without error, but didn't work, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zfs-linux package in Ubuntu 18.04 does not work with Kernel 4.16 - 4.19.
I haven't found a solution.
Kernel 4.15 works, but it seems to have a bug on some platforms with keyboard and mouse lag.